# Help with SQL Express and appending data to third party platform

Tags: sql-server

New to DB Admin and kind of learning as I’m going to get to where I need to be.

Basically, I have an account on a third party data software and my organization purchased additional data (from another vendor) that I would like to append to this. The two platforms identify records by the same unique ID#

I have a 2.6GB .tab file (2.6 million rows) that have around 70 variables per row. Normally, I would just open in Excel, filter, and match using the third party’s tag management system. But obviously this .tab file is too large.

I’m trying to use SQL Express to get the data in a usable form, but having trouble populating the data table. Am I even going about this in the right way?

*EDIT** I should add: I can get the full .tab file into the Excel Power Pivot, but not really useful considering I need to figure out a way to tag and upload

I have the .tab file split up into smaller chunks (500K rows each), and can open and manipulate these, but I’d like to keep the database consistent so I can cross reference the unique ID numbers later with some of the data I don’t necessarily need to upload and append into the third party platform.

Any guidance would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: I don’t know anything about .tab but sql server `bulk insert` is what you want to check out if .tab can be a flat file, delimited.

Comment: It seems import and export wizard would be suitable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017